# Javascript color split string

Tags: string, text, colors, split

I'm using the following code to process some strings the when it gets down to the innerHTML part I want to color the tittxt0 variable string data blue. I know how to do it if I get a dom element but I don't know how to color just the tittxt0 variable data and leave 
limit chars0 alone. Thanks for your time.

```
var tittxt0 = txt0[i].split("++++")[0];
var txt00 = txt0[i].split("++++")[1];
var limitchars0 = txt00.substring(0,100);
var limitchars1 = txt00.substring(100, txt00.length);
var codecou0=limitchars1.split("[code]");
if(codecou0.length>1){paras0[i].innerHTML ="[code]" }
if(limitchars0.length ==80){
    paras0[i].innerHTML += tittxt0+"<br>"+limitchars0+ " ...";
    tittxt0.style.color="blue";
}else{
    paras0[i].innerHTML += tittxt0+"<br>"+limitchars0;
    tittxt0.style.color="blue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by makeing on varaiable inside  a paragraph and inserting the other variable inside a strong element here is the complete function for whoever needs it.

```
callrecb0:function(rectxt){
var forumcon0 = document.getElementsByClassName("forumcon0");

var txt0 = rectxt.split(":::");


for(var i=0; i<txt0.length; i++){ 

var newpara0=document.createElement("p");
forumcon0[0].appendChild(newpara0);
var paras0=forumcon0[0].getElementsByTagName("p");
paras0[i].setAttribute("id", "x"+i);
custevents.addevent(paras0[i], 'click',custevents.forlink0);
var tittxt0 = txt0[i].split("++++")[0];
var txt00 = txt0[i].split("++++")[1];
var limitchars0 = txt00.substring(0,35);
if(limitchars0.length==35){
var limitchars00 = txt00.substring(36,71);
}else{
limitchars00="";
}
var limitchars1 = txt00.substring(71, txt00.length);
//var limitTotatl0 = limitchars0.length+limitchars00.length;
//alert(limitTotal0);
//paras0[i].innerHTML += tittxt0+"<br>"
  paras0[i].style.color="Blue";
  var codecou0=limitchars1.split("[code]");
  if(codecou0.length>1){paras0[i].innerHTML ="[code]" }
  if(limitchars00.length >34){
  paras0[i].innerHTML += tittxt0+"<br>"
  paras0[i].style.color="Blue";
  var newpara1=document.createElement("strong");
  paras0[i].appendChild(newpara1);
  newpara1.style.color="black";
  newpara1.innerHTML+=limitchars0+"<br>"+limitchars00+" ...";

  }else{
  paras0[i].innerHTML += tittxt0+"<br>"
  paras0[i].style.color="Blue";
  var newpara1=document.createElement("strong");
  paras0[i].appendChild(newpara1);
  newpara1.innerHTML+=limitchars0+"<br>"+limitchars00;
  newpara1.style.color="black";
  }
  if(i==txt0.length-2){
  formstyle.odd();
     }
   }

  },
```